# MVC Custom Role Provider not being hit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, roleprovider

I added a custom role provider but for whatever reason its not being used, it seems like the default is keep getting used. Here is my code for custom role provider

```
namespace Models.Security
{
    public class MatchMakerRoleProvider: RoleProvider
    {
        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            username = username.Split('\\')[1].ToLower();
            using (var db = new EncodingEntities())
            {
                var user = db.Admin_Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));


                    var roles = from ur in user.Admin_UserRoles
                        from r in db.Admin_Roles
                        where ur.RoleId == r.RoleId
                        select r.RoleName;
                    if (roles != null)
                        return roles.ToArray();
                    else
                        return new string[] {};
            }
        }

        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            using (var db = new EncodingEntities())
            {
                var user = db.Admin_Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

                var roles = from ur in user.Admin_UserRoles
                            from r in db.Admin_Roles
                            where ur.RoleId == r.RoleId
                            select r.RoleName;
                if (user != null)
                    return roles.Any(r => r.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
```

And Web.Config

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MatchMakerRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MatchMakerRoleProvider" type="Models.Security.MatchMakerRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

If I set a breakpoint in my CustomRoleProvider, it never gets hit...

Any Ideas ?

Comment: The debugger isn't always hit when using components like this.  For whatever reason, they don't get wired up in the debugger correctly.  Instead, add Debugger.Break() statements to force the debugger to stop.

Comment: Actually, I also notice that your namespace does not match the namespace you list in your web.config.

Comment: Actually I changed that just for OP Ill fix that, thats a non issue in actual code. Also I tried added debugged thing and still doesnt get hit

Comment: If the provider is in a different assembly, you will likely have to specify the assembly name in the type parameter as well.

Comment: not its in the same solution....I actually just had some luck by getting rid of this in web config cacheRolesInCookie="true" as part of the rolemanager section

Comment: That just means you needed to delete your cookie.. you should probably keep the setting but delete your cookie when you need to test.  Or remember to add the setting back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the custom provider code in a separate project in your solution and added as a reference to the MVC project in your solution? If so, you may need to have something like:

```
<add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="Namespace.For.CustomRoleProvider, Your.Assembly.Name" />
```

Comment: not its in the same solution....I actually just had some luck by getting rid of this in web config cacheRolesInCookie="true" as part of the rolemanager section

Comment: This fixed the issue for me too, but I can't help thinking we're ignoring the underlying problem. It should be possible to cache roles, surely?