# ASP.NET MVC custom role provider not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, roles, asp.net-authorization

I have setup a custom role provider implemented using the code below except it seems it's never being used, and the default provider is being used instead. When decorating the HomeController with the `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` attribute the `CustomRoleProvider` constructor is being called (I only included the constructor in to see whether the breakpoint would be hit) but none of the methods are being called.  And then I am left with a `HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized` page.

Aside from adding the necessary bits to the web.config I haven't done anything else to get Windows authentication to work.  I assume it's working though because if I don't include `<allow users="*"></allow>` (obviously without the inclusion of the `Authorize` attribute) I get a `401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration` error, so I assume I'm being authenticated.

I've cleared my browser cookies as per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105321/mvc-custom-role-provider-not-being-hit) but that had no effect.

**CustomerRoleProvider**

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public CustomRoleProvider()
    {            
    }

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        bool isUserInRole = false;

        // omitted for brevity

        return isUserInRole;
    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        string[] roles = null;

        // omitted for brevity

        return roles;
    }

    // omitted for brevity

}
```

**web.config**

```
    <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"></allow>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="ProjectName.UI.Mvc.Code.Providers.CustomRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

**Home Controller**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the Roles attribute, and just use solely the [Authorize] decorator?

Comment: Nope, still get the `HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized` error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was caused from not having IIS Express set to use Windows Authentication. To fix I selected the project in Solution Explorer, opened the Properties window set `Windows Authentication = Enabled` and `Anonymous Authentication = Disabled`.  Custom role provider now works.

Comment: I'm using VS 2015. When I open the properties window I do not see anywhere to change the settings you describe. Is there another way to check these settings?

Comment: I was using VS 2013, so I'm not sure where the setting is in VS 2015.  It would be odd if it's not in the same place though.

Comment: The properties that you are looking for are not the one with alt+enter but in F4. Total different panel usually opened as a side panel.

Comment: Spent half a day wondering why my extended Authorize attribute wasn't calling my custom RoleProvider. Turns if it was this. I had anonymous and windows auth enabled. +1